# Visual Studio Unit Test - "XUnit format?"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing

My taskmasters have tasked me with attempting to get output from Visual Studio Unit Tests for C#. Evidently, our build environment can make use of output files in that format. I hear rumors it is possible, but my Googling comes up empty.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this feat?

Comment: Not sure I understand. XUnit is not a fileformat. It is a unit test tool: https://xunit.github.io/

Comment: @peter We are probably just a bunch of people throwing around terms we don't understand. That's how requirements usually go :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run your tests with [VSTest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155796.aspx) or [MSTest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182489.aspx) from the command line to create a .trx file with your test results. This is the standard format used for Visual Studio Unit Test output.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in other answer, MSTest.exe will generate trx files that xUnit is able to parse.

If you have one script that builds all your projects, you might want to execute all tests and aggregate all test results into one trx file for xUnit. 
Good practice is to name all your test projects to end with '.Test'. All these projects compile into dll's and they will all end with '.Test.dll'.

Then you can update your build script to pick up all test projects, by searching your repo for Test.dll files in a script like this:

```
@SET _config=Release

@call "%VS110COMNTOOLS%vsvars32"
@setlocal enabledelayedexpansion enableextensions
@set list=
@for /R ".." %%x in (obj) do @(
    @set CTD=%%x
    @pushd !CTD!
    @for %%y in (%_config%\*Test.dll %_config%\*Tests.dll) do @set list=!list! /testcontainer:%%x\..\bin\%%y
    @popd
) 2>nul

@set list=%list:~1%

@del results.trx 2>nul
mstest %list% /resultsfile:results.trx /detail:stdout
@IF NOT %ERRORLEVEL%==0 (GOTO lbl_error)

:lbl_success
@ECHO Successfully ran tests.
@GOTO lbl_end

:lbl_error
@ECHO Failed to run tests.
@EXIT /b 1
```